# How to use only one connection string accross one solution?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a solution where I have more than 10 projects and in each project I need to connect to database. Is there anyway to centralize and get connection string only from one web.config file?

Comment: Data Layer, Entity Model

Answer (score 1):

Just put the connection strings inside the `Web.config`.

Library projects don't have their own config files; instead, they use the AppDomain's configuration file, which in your case would be the `Web.config`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have a Data Layer as you've indicated, it should be the only module/project that needs a connection string.

Answer (score 0):

inside your web.config put

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="connstrings.config"/>
</configuration>
```

create a file in the root directory of your website called connstring.config and put the following inside it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="local"
         connectionString="Data Source=dbserver;Initial Catalog=databasename;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=false;Connect Timeout=5;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

create class in your project called Database.cs and put the following in it

```
using System.Configuration;
public class Database
{
    public class ConnStrings
    {
        public static string local = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["local"].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

now whenever you need the conn string, you can use `Database.ConnStrings.local`

Comment: actually, i may have been a bit quick on the answer there... you question can be interpreted a few ways